# Are there any Identity Providers that support the Assertion Query/Request Profile described in SAML2 profiles spec.?

Tags: security, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to understand the SAML2 [Assertion Query/Request Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#Assertion_Query.2FRequest_Profile), but not finding much documentation about it. Are there any identity providers that support it. If yes, it'd be helpful to see some documentation around it. Also, are there any alternatives to this profile which more or less address the same use case?

Comment: Have you looked at SAML-Core?

Comment: You mean the Spec? Yeah, but I'm trying to figure out if I can use it in my code.Not finding much about it when I go through the various IdP documentation.All they talk about is the WebSSO profile.

Answer (score 0):

[Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/) supports standard SAML 2.0 Attribute Query profile, you can find details on IDP configuration in the [Shibboleth documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPSAML2AttributeQueryProfileConfig).

IDP usually provides all the attributes SP might need already during SSO, so there's no need to load additional ones. Attributes required by the SP can be declared in its metadata document.